# n-widths and  Kolmogorov's entropy 

Tags: it.information-theory, na.numerical-analysis, reference-request

Most of the authors of research papers in compressed sensing use  n-widths and Kolmogorov's entropy extensively, which are kind of hard for me to understand. Any suggestion on books  or expository articles about these will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Nvm the edit - it's null.

Answer (score 4):

You can try *An Introduction to Kolmogorov Complexity and Its Applications* by Ming Li and Paul Vitányi, it's an excellent book.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite what you asked for, but possibly useful if you haven't yet read it, is Baraniuk et al, [A Simple Proof of the Restricted Isometry Property for Random Matrices](http://dsp.rice.edu/sites/dsp.rice.edu/files/cs/JL_RIP.pdf). This was one of the most readable introductions that I found when I was learning about CS.

For the basics of Kolmogorov Complexity you could do worse than Cover and Thomas, Elements of Information Theory.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing can surpass the Li and Vitányi book in both readability and comprehensiveness,
but that is a significant undertaking, and you might need alternatives.
"[A Short Introduction to Kolmogorov Complexity](http://arxiv.org/abs/1005.2400)" by Volker Nannen, true to its title, is only 7 pages long. The [Wikipedia page on Kolmogorov Complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_complexity) is quite good.
Gregory Chaitin's *[Exploring Randomness](http://books.google.com/books?id=SypgS22V-TgC&printsec=frontcover&dq=Exploring+Randomness&source=bl&ots=JQwAIn-qga&sig=kpmpXyagWkLI5-24mkXzhwvMA0g&hl=en&ei=34ZFTPv-N4H68Abou7zmBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false)* is a fun, quirky, personalized view of the field, emphasizing his own work and LISP programs. Caveat: his philosophical musings are quite controversial.
In fact, reading the balanced [Notices of the AMS review](http://www.ams.org/notices/200109/rev-panu.pdf) of his book by Panu Raatikainen might serve as a useful introduction to the area.

Answer (score 1):

The book that is my reference (and also the reference I found in a lot of excellent papers on the subjects) is the book by Pinkus:
n-Widths in Approximation Theory, Springer-Verlag, Berlin (1985)

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend "Nonlinear Methods of Approximation" by V.N.Temlyakov.